# SonarQube plugin for Jenkins Sonar section not visible

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner

I installed the SonarQube plugin, definitely not the Sonargraph plugin, but in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System there's no Sonar section to configure.  I have SonarQube Runner though but i need to be able to tell the system where my SQ server is.

Sound like a bug or am i missing something?

Jenkins v 1.621
SonarQube plugin v 2.2.1
SonarQube Server v 5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The configuration section is called 'Sonar', not 'SonarQube' under Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. You can add/ manage SonarQube installations there.

Are you not able to find it there?